# How do I retrieve the modified by information for a keyword using core services?

Tags: 2013

How can I retrieve the modified by information for a keyword? Using the following code I am getting only the creator and modified date:

```
KeywordData keyword = (KeywordData)client.Read("tcmid", new ReadOptions());
```

Are there any method or properties in core services to get all the modified information for a keyword?

Comment: Keywords are not versioned.

Comment: This would also apply to other non-versioned items such as Organizational Items. A quick check in the Content Explorer is by seeing when (Versioning) History is enabled for a selected item.

Answer (score 8):

Keywords are not versioned items, so Tridion does not keep historical data for them. This is why your KeywordData's VersionInfo property returns you a LimitedVersionInfo object, rather than a FullVersionInfo object

Comment: +1. If this answer works for you, @Rameshponna, feel free to accept as one more (official) "thank you" to David. :-)